# Detecting rising and falling temperature C

Tags: c, microcontroller, temperature

I'm trying to detect rising and falling temperatures using PIC16F877A MCU and two DS8B20 sensors. I'm facing with problems when I try to detect temperature falling. Here is my code what am I trying to do:

```
#include "main.h"

void main() {

    //Turn on LCD backlight
    output_high(PIN_D7);

    // Initialize LCD module
    lcd_init();

    float Threshold_Value = 30;  // Temperature threshold value

    while (TRUE) {

        Show_User_Info();
        delay_ms(10);
        Read_Sensors();

        // Starting to read user button values
        User_Buttons();
        delay_ms(20);               // Minimum amount of time to read user button  values

        // Starting to compare user set temperature value and upper sensor temperature  read value.
        Compare_Upper_Temp();
        delay_ms(20);

        //================================

        // Checking, if the MCU pin connected to pump is high. If yes - do the waiting 'animation'
        if (input(PIN_B5)) {

            while(temp > Threshold_Value);
            {
                Bottom_Waiting_Animation();
            }

            // Experimenting....
            // break;
            // continue;
        }

        if (input(PIN_B5)) {
            while(temp < Threshold_Value);
            {
                Bottom_Waiting_Animation();
            }
            // break;
        }

        // If the set temp is less than threshold - turn the pump off.

        if (temp < Threshold_Value) {
            input(PIN_B5) == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When the pump is switched on, I need to wait until second sensor reaches threshold value (30C), after that I need to 'detect' when that temperature starts to drop from that 30C. This code which I uploaded 'works' only with one While(temp > Threshold_Value) loop. But when I insert the next one under it while(temp < Threshold_Value), MCU jumps in undefined area and gets stuck. This task sounds pretty easy, but I tried lots of different ways to solve this problem. Maybe one of the problem reasons could be multiple while loops?

Comment: You probably want to create a thermostat. For this task PID controllers are used.  Here you have a very basic explanation and the code. https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIDLibrary/

Comment: @P__J__ you generally don't need a PID controller for a thermostat. Generally. Sometimes you do. But mostly it's just "on when too hot, off when too cold" (or vice versa)

Comment: @user253751 Sorry but it is a very naive approach. Everything controlled usually you needs on or off. But PIDs are used. For a reason.

Comment: @P__J__ True, PIDs are used for a reason, but "bang-bang" controllers are also used for a reason.  Do you know the reasons to choose between the two?  Are you aware that most thermostats are bang-bang controllers?  In any case, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: A simple debugging session would have found that errant semicolon.

Comment: @TomServo makes a very important point.  For starters, add some printf statements in your code to see if you're getting where you expect.  Then learn to use a debugger like gdb.  Google "debugging simple C programs".

Comment: BTW, to post code, first remove all tabs.  Then paste it in, select it all, and click the `{}` widget, which will shift it right 4 spaces causing it to be rendered as code.  Also, be careful about indentation in your code because it **really** helps you spot errors.

Comment: @JeffLearman I do not know if you have noticed - but it is comment not the answer

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a semicolon after the `while` condition.

Replace

```
while (condition);
{
    ... looped code ...
}
```

with

```
while (condition)
{
    .... looped code ...
}
```

This is one reason I like to put open braces at the end of the condition (as you do in your `if` statements): it helps to see the obnoxious accidental semicolon.

Comment: Lots of spinning with `while(temp > Threshold_Value);` but very little animating going on... And the same with the next loop..

Comment: More than once... Thank goodness gcc added the warning for misleading indention that catches it now `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Another great point!  Always use `-Werror` option when compiling (if using gcc)!  This catches a lot of bugs before they lay eggs and multiply.